# How to set CSS properties of child html tag with typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have the following HTML:

```
<li id="test">
    <span>Anything</span>
    <button>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="assets/icon/sprite.svg#icon-check"></use>
        </svg>
    </button>
</li>
```

And I have a function that changes the bottom color of the `li` tag (and works properly)

```
private setColor(): void {
  const rowId = 'test'; 

  const row = document.getElementById(rowId) as HTMLElement;

  const colorToSet = '#33be09';
  row.style.borderBottomColor = colorToSet;
}
```

My issue is that I also want to change the color of the `svg`, but I can't access the `svg` in my function. I've tried the `children` function, but I don't know how to access specifically the `svg`. How can I do this?

Comment: Please try `row.querySelector('svg')`